# How to push multi select values to Jquery array when looping through a table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC foreach table with a multiselect drop down list in it. Is it possible to create AND store an array based on the values in that row then once the row is finished, do it again?

I'll elaborate further below.

Here is a picture of the table. You can see the multiple values I need to capture.  [image: Table with multi select drop down list]

Here is what I can do: I can ID what row and column these values are on and I can store them all in an array and display them.

What I need to do is take the values in row: 0. store those in an array then I'll send those off to a controller for processing. come back and do the same for row: 1 and row: 2. However, I'm not able to identify how to do so when the row changes.

Here is my Jquery function which captures and displays.

```
$('#alSubmitButton').on('click', function () {
var rowCount = $('#alSublineValSubmitTBL >tbody >tr').length;

var selected = [];


$("table#alSublineValSubmitTBL >tbody >tr").each(function (i) {
    $(".mcalSymbols :selected", this).each(function (j) {
        console.log("".concat("row: ", i, ", col: ", j, ", value: ", $(this).text()));  
        selected.push($(this).text());

    });
         //AT SOME POINT HERE WHEN THE ROW (i) INCREASES. I will send selected array to another function. 
        //This is exactly the point I need some assistance. How can I recognize when row i changes 
        //from 0 to 1 and 1 to 2.. etc  ? (Could be up to 13 potential rows here) 

});
  console.log(selected);
});
```

Here's a pic of the console.log with the current output

[image]

You can see I have the row and col identified. I'm also outputting all values selected. Would like to take the values in row 0. Put them in an array.. send them off to a controller. do the same thing for row 1 and 2. Your guidance and help is always appreciated.

UPDATE: Adding the View Model I'm using to display the results

```
 public class CIF_SubLines_InsertVM
{
    public CIF_SubLines_InsertVM()
    {
        //emtpy constructor
    }

    public CIF_SubLines_InsertVM(CIF_SubLines_InsertDTO row)
    {
        UniqSublineID = row.UniqSublineID;
        UniqSublineType = row.UniqSublineType;
        UniqLineType = row.UniqLineType;
        UniqLine = row.UniqLine;
        UniqPolicy = row.UniqPolicy;
        Selected = row.Selected;
        SubLineName = row.SubLineName;
    }

    public Guid UniqSublineID { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqSublineType { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqLineType { get; set; }
    public int UniqLine { get; set; }
    public int UniqPolicy { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string SubLineName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why don't you send "selected" to controller and do all of it at the same time in controller ?

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou can I see the properties of your model that is attached on the view? I think we could make a view model to handle that. But the key is submitting them all on hidden input fields.

Comment: @Nhien normally that's exactly what I would do, but I need to isolate the 'selected' values to the respective row. Because each selected value will be inserted individually into a DB row. Along with other key values associated with the 'BI/PD' row as well as the others.   I.e. the values associated with row 0 'BI/PD' have other keys I'm using to submit to the DB.. but any of those numbers in any combination can be used, so the controller would only see the full array. It wouldn't know row 0 has 2 values. Row 1 has 1 value and row 3 has 0 values. Dealing with it on the front end seemed logical

Comment: @Jerdine Sabio can't do it right now, but I'll post the model for it tomorrow so you can see it.

Comment: @Jerdine Sabio  I just posted the current View Model I use to display the view itself.